# What tool is needed to remove KMC X11 w/MissingLink, 11-speed chain?

Tags: chain, tools

I need to take it out and then clean it- its full of sand. Maybe even replace it. Does any universal chain tool work. Should I get one from the manufacturer.

Comment: I had success opening/closing KMC 11 speed missing link with MLP 1.2, probably any missing link tool will work, you can even make your own from pliers or scissors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any tool that can be used on an 11-speed chain should work to 'break-the-link', i.e. push the pin (rivet) out.  I have never updated my [Park CT-3](http://www.parktool.com/product/chain-tool-ct-3-2?category=Chain) tool in years and have used it on a variety of chain variations, from 8 speed up to 11.

You should look for a [KMC replacement master link](http://www.kmcchain.eu/connector-road_cross), as most manufacturers do not recommend using other manufacturer's master links.

I'm not a huge fan of pushing pins back in place, but if you have the right tool, it is doable, the simplicity of the self-locking master links makes reconnecting the chain way easier--I carry both 10- and 11- speed links with my, never know when you might need one, or can help someone out, they are light and cheap enough.

I personally have the KMC Connector and Removal tools, I really like the connector tool, as the 'stomp-on-the-pedal' method seems sketchy, imo.

Comment: i got the manufacturers tool and it worked fine. Thank you.